# DataTemplate to work as a Panel - how to create one?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentpresenter

I want to define a common appearence for a handful of DataTemplates. As such, I would like an "outer" DataTemplate with nested containers, much like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FancyPanel">
    <Border>
        <Border>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <!-- the actual container should be here
                     would a ContentPresenter work? -->
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="FancyFooTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Foo}">
    <FancyPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Bar}"/>  <!-- binds to Foo.Bar -->
    </FancyPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Of course `FancyPanel` doesn't exist, since it isn't a Control. I know I can derive from UserControl and put the borders and scrollviewer there, but I wonder if that can be made purely with resources in xaml. And even so, I would have to tell where to put its Child(ren).

Comment: Use a `ContentControl` someplace where you want to wrap some other content. For example, replace `<FancyPanel>` with `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FancyPanel}">`

Comment: @Rachel how can I tell `FancyPanel` where to put the content? In my example, there is the ScrollViewer, which should have "something" inside to receive the content, with its respective, independent template.

Comment: @heltonbiker that is not how it works. `ControlTemplate` can have content in form of `ContentPresenter` or `ItemsPresenter`. That content can be visualised via `DataTemplate`. `DataTemplate` doesn't have content it becomes content. Create custom control derived from `ContentControl` and create custom `ControlTemplate` where you can say where content goes

Comment: @dkozl What you wrote above makes perfect sense, I think this is my problem: not having figured out that I needed a ControlTemplate. Do you think I can create one _without_ subclassing ContentControl, but instead using some existing WPF control derived from ContentControl?

Comment: You need to create new control only if you add new functionality or make your template default for that control type. Otherwise just use `ContentControl` as is and apply template manually. Even (dependency) properties can be attached later